# Can we just upvote questions more?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

Don't have much to say.  I thumb through questions.  I upvote anything that contains all info needed and is not a repeat.  However I often see comments on the question from our top 30 users and see no upvotes for the user's question.  Just upvote good questions.  If a topic spurs 10 comments and the comments aren't asking for more info then it is probably a good question and should have 5-6 upvotes.  Voting will help drive traffic to the site.  Anyone disagree?

Comment: It's a problem on every SE site. My only question here prompted 3 answers and multiple comments and I only got 1 vote (the top answer got 5 votes).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9508/161554

Comment: This is what a very generous user on mechanics.SE did: http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/earn-the-electorate-badge-in-january-2016-and-get